# Password box on boot up

Tags: 14.04, boot, password

Still a newbie.  Using a clean maching, purchased from System 76 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.  Got it mid-May of 2014.

Key words: Ubuntu 14.04 boot password

When I start my machine, I am taken to the last desktop I was using whether I logged out previously or not.  (I switch between
Unity and KDE).  On that screen, with the system asking me for my password, I can, without entering my password, use my applications.
Granted I have this diolog box in my way, but still, I can use my apps.  That doesn't seem so safe to me.

I have my system set so that when I "suspend" and come back, I am asked for my password but it's not the desktop.  It's a screen where
I can choose whatever destop I like. Now that's secure.  And that's the screen I want when I boot up.  How can I get that?

Thank you,

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings, Users, then you unlock your user. After that you turn off the option to enter automatically in your account. I think that is that, 'cause my Ubuntu is not in English. Hope that it solved your problem.

Comment: Ha!  Thank you Lephy!  "Automatic Login".  Wouldn't you know?  :)  Thanks man.  I appreciate it!